# Azure Service Bus working behind proxy

Tags: azure

I am using the Azure service bus via the SDK, It is all working fine but I am having problems which I think are proxy related. With IE running it all works fine, but if it is not running the messages fails to send. I am setting the proxy up in code but was wondering if I am doing this correctly for the service bus SDK

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(m_Config.ProxyAddress);
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ProxyUser, ProxyPassword, ProxyDomain);

WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;

QueueClient client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);

client.Send(message);
```

Comment: It will be really helpfull if your provide the **concrete** failure indications - like **concrete** exception message + stacktrace.

Comment: The error that I am getting is listed below but I am doing the right think by setting the proxy up with WebRequest?

Comment: Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingCommunicationException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format. ---> System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format. ---> System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication
   at

Comment: Solved the issue, the problem as that for some reason I had to force " ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Http" as AutoDetect was not working as expected. Works fine now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue, the problem as that for some reason I had to force " ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Http" as AutoDetect was not working as expected. Works fine now