# Why does console apps use proxy by default?

Tags: c#, azure, proxy

I am currently having some issues with class library that doesn't behave as its console app.

The purpose of the console app is to send messages to an azure queue, which it does without any problem, and can see in ressource monitor that it makes calls through our web proxy and to our azure queue. This is done by default, I haven't told it anyway that it should use this proxy.

The class library on the other hand, does the same thing, but does not use the proxy, and therefore not able to send its data.

Both projects are identical, in the way they make the call to send a message, but for some reason is the console app, which intention is only to send a message, and library which intention is the same, act differently -  why does the console app try to use proxy, and how do i force the class library to forcefully use the proxy?

conclusion:

How do i force a `Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QueueClient.send` 
to use a proxy and not port 443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question.

I resolved the issue by creating a proxy.config , and add it to my app.config.

proxy.config format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<defaultProxy enabled="true">
    <proxy autoDetect="False" proxyaddress="http://<proxyaddress>:<port>" />
    <bypasslist>
        <add address="localhost" />
    </bypasslist>
</defaultProxy>
```

and add the proxy.config into my app.config as a system.net configuration:

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy configSource="proxy.config" />
  </system.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, It is impossible to set the proxy while using service bus client.

The only connection options for Service Bus client are as following:

HTTP - port 80

HTTPS - port 443

TCP -  9350 to 9354

For more information we can refer to:

[ConnectivityMode Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.connectivitymode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azure-dotnet#microsoft_servicebus_connectivitymode)

In your class library, please set the connectivity mode to Http as below code and try again:

```
ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Http;
```

Similar thread as yours: [Azure Service Bus working behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31076054/azure-service-bus-working-behind-proxy)