# Azure Service Bus Issue authenticating behind proxy

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azureservicebus

I'm trying to implement Azure Service Bus integration with `ASP.NET Core` with background task to run background process. I am following guide from this [source](https://github.com/stewartadam/aspnet-servicebus-hostedservice/blob/master/Services/BusListenerService.cs) and I have encountered an issue that I believe is due to my system in behind proxy. I looked at this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31076054/azure-service-bus-working-behind-proxy) and it appears that it is not for `.net core`.

When I cloned this [project](https://github.com/stewartadam/aspnet-servicebus-hostedservice) locally, and after updating the appsettings with correct service bus connection string, I got below error after building and running the project locally.

```
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusCommunicationException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__46_2(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.TaskHelpers.EndAsyncResult(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TlsTransport.HandleOpenComplete(IAsyncResult result, Boolean syncComplete)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpObject.OpenAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpObject.EndOpen(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TlsTransportInitiator.HandleTransportOpened(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TlsTransportInitiator.OnTransportOpened(IAsyncResult result)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusConnection.CreateConnectionAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.OnCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpLinkCreator.CreateAndOpenAmqpLinkAsync()
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver.CreateLinkAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.OnCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver.OnReceiveAsync(Int32 maxMessageCount, TimeSpan serverWaitTime)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver.OnReceiveAsync(Int32 maxMessageCount, TimeSpan serverWaitTime)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver.<>c__DisplayClass64_0.<<ReceiveAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.RunOperation(Func`1 operation, TimeSpan operationTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.RunOperation(Func`1 operation, TimeSpan operationTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver.ReceiveAsync(Int32 maxMessageCount, TimeSpan operationTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan operationTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageReceivePump.<MessagePumpTaskAsync>b__11_0()
```

I wanted to check if anyone has encountered this before and if there is a way to set proxy for service bus to connect behind proxy network? If not, I may have to use the rest api with `httpclient`.

Answer (score 0):

seems like something to do with security protocol. can you please try adding this code

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did try that in my .net core project, but doesnt seem to help. I dont think this applies to .net core. I added in `project.cs` in `main` method, and also directly in `BusListenerService.cs`, but that didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the correct outbound ports?  Check out [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2017/11/07/open-port-requirements-and-ip-address-whitelisting/) MSDN blog post.

> - Azure Service Bus requires the use of TLS at all times.
> - It supports    connections over TCP port 5671 and over TCP port 5672. The server    immediately offers a mandatory upgrade to TLS using the    AMQP-prescribed model. The AMQP WebSockets binding
>     creates a tunnel    over TCP port 443 that is then equivalent to AMQP
>     5671 connections.
> - Both modern (.Net Standard and Java) clients use AMQP, hence the    above guidance applies.
> - The older .NET library has a custom, WCF    based protocol that used TCP and port 9354 (called SBMP, Service Bus    Messaging
>     Protocol).
> - If you solely use our rest API you may be able    to open only port 443.